# ¿como llamar a una función dentro de otra función que se encuentra en otro modulo?

Tags: python-3.x

aquí continuando aprendiendo a programar, hoy tengo un duda que quiero despejar, después de leer y buscar esta mi duda no encontré algo similar. Pues estoy realizando un programa y me tope con esta duda que es la siguiente: como llamar de un modulo fun_uno(), a una función llamada saludo_hola_mundo (), que esta se encuentra dentro la función saludo_hola() y esta en otro modulo llamado fun_dos(); se puede realizar tal tarea o no, porque en mi programa es necesario que una función se encuentre dentro otra función y necesito llamar de otro modulo a dicha función.

Aquí les dejo en resumen un pequeño ejemplo de lo que busco, y gracias de antemano.

```
#modulo  fun_dos.py
class Dos:
    def __init__ (self):
        pass
    def saludo_hola (self):
        print ("hola")
        def saludo_hola_mundo (self): # como llamar esta funcion en modulo fun_uno.py
            print ("hola mundo")
    
def saludo_final ():
    print ("Chau")

#modulo  fun_uno.py

from fun_dos import Dos, saludo_final

saludo_1 = Dos ()
saludo_1.saludo_hola ()
saludo_2 = saludo_final() # hasta aqui no hay problema

saludo_1.saludo_hola().saludo_hola_mundo() # como llamar a saludo_hola_mundo ()
                                       # si esta función se encuentra dentro de otra función ?
```

Comment: La propósito de definir una función dentro de otra es precisamente ocultarla del resto del mundo. Seguro que hay una forma de lograr lo que quieres, pero hay ejercicios más beneficiosos.

Comment: Tal vez estaria bueno que expliques porque crees que tu unica solucion es una funcion dentro de otra...

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, y si hay alguna forma de lograrlo, entonces seguro que encontrare. Pues no creo que sea mi única solución, pero para mi programa me es más práctico porque utilizo condicionales if para esa única función del programa que ninguna otra función lo tiene; como estoy aprendiendo python, pues quiero practicar todas las opciones posibles que exista.

Answer (score 1):

La idea de tener funciones dentro de funciones es para protegerlas del exterior y evitar el global scope.

Sin embargo si deseas hacer lo que estás solicitando, tengo una propuesta para ti.

Dentro de `fun_dos.py` agrega lo siguiente:

```
#modulo  fun_dos.py
class Dos:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def saludo_hola(self):
        print ("hola")
        def saludo_hola_mundo(self): # como llamar esta funcion en modulo fun_uno.py
            return "hola mundo" #Cambias print por return
        a = saludo_hola_mundo(self) #Llamas a saludo_hola_mundo() y lo asignas a variable
        print(a) #imprimes en pantalla
    
def saludo_final():
    print ("Chau")
```

Hablando de `fun_uno.py`

```
from fun_dos import Dos, saludo_final

saludo_1 = Dos ()
saludo_1.saludo_hola ()
saludo_2 = saludo_final() # hasta aqui no hay problema

#NOTA: Esto ya no lo necesitas por eso lo he comentado
#saludo_1.saludo_hola().saludo_hola_mundo() # como llamar a saludo_hola_mundo ()
                                       # si esta función se encuentra dentro de otra función ?
```

Resultado:

```
hola
hola mundo
Chau
```

Recomiendo que revises el tema de Inner Functions y LEGB para tener mayor control de tu código.